# Interesting behaviour: Object literal may only specify known properties

Tags: typescript

There're similar questions here and I can understand the nature of this error:

```
type Person = { name: string };

// Error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'age' does not exist in type 'Person'.
const person: Person = { name: 'Sarah', age: 13 };
```

So this fails, because property `age` is not a part of type `Person` which makes sense.

However, I can do this without any problems:

```
type Person = { name: string };

const obj = { name: 'Sarah', age: 13 };
const person: Person = obj;

console.log(person); // { name: 'Sarah', age: 13 }
```

Why the first one is failing and the second is not - shouldn't these 2 examples both fail or both pass?

As for me these 2 code snippets are identical. Aren't they?

Update:

Here's an explanation of this behaviour from [Typescript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks):

> Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property
>   checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as
>   arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the “target
>   type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error.

Comment: this is so twisty

Answer (score 3):

As of TypeScript 1.6, properties in object literals that do not have a corresponding property in the type they're being assigned to are flagged as errors.

Basically: the TS compiler knows that the age will never be used, thats why its angry at you. In the second example it doesnt know that age will never be used as its part of a normal object. Once it gets copied to the Person only the name continues to exist

TLDR: when initializing with a literal the TSC is strict

Answer (score 1):

Let me elaborate on the update provided by @dmitry-papka.

Here, the TypeScript is balancing two things :

- Structural Typing
- Strict Type Checking to catch errors

**Think of types as **Sets of values**.**

When any custom type (either `primitive` or `object`) is created, it adds a constraint. It limits the infinite set of possible values to finite set of possibilities. It is like a contract.

The type `Person` in `type Person = { name: string };` declares a contract. Any value which have a `name` property whose domain/value is a `string` will obey the contract.

For example, the following code is valid:

```
 const p: Person = window;
```

The `window` or `global` object in browser obeys the contract as it has *bunch of other properties along with* `name` property whose domain/value is `string`.

This is what Structural Typing or Duck Typing is all about: "If it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it's a duck".

But this limits catching errors.

Suppose, a optional property `height` is added to `Person` interface.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  height? : number; // <-- optional property
}

function greet(person: Person) : void {
console.log(person.height);
}

greet({ 
name: 'Brave',
hieght: 180 // <--- typo, which would be silent in case of pure structural typing
})
```

Therefore, TypeScript adds a **strict object literal checking** whenever an object literal is assigned to a variable or passed as an argument to the function.

To bypass the excess property checking, we can:

- use an intermediate variable like `obj`

```
type Person = { name: string };

// declare intermediate variable 
const obj = { name: 'Sarah', age: 13 };
const person: Person = obj; // <--- `obj` is not an object literal

console.log(person); // { name: 'Sarah', age: 13 }
```

- use Type assertion

```
type Person = { name: string };

const person = { name: 'Sarah', age: 13 } as Person; // <-- type assertion
```